# How to call a function in another cpp file in mex file?

Tags: c++, matlab, c++11

I am testing to call another function in my mex file. But I came across a building error. 
" "void __cdecl transferarray1(struct mxArray_tag
const *,class std::vector > &)"
(??$transferarray1@H@@YAXPEBUmxArray_tag@@AEAV?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@@Z) test.mexw64 : fatal error LNK1120"
My code is below:
test.cpp:

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <vector>
#include "inoutmex.h"
using namespace std;
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
vector<int> idx;
transferarray1(prhs[0],idx);
}
```

inoutmex.cpp

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <typename T> 
void transferarray1(const mxArray *ix, vector<T>&V)
{
    mwSize num = mxGetNumberOfElements(ix);
    mxDouble *ptr;
    ptr = mxGetPr(ix);
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)num; i++)
    {
        V.push_back(T(*ptr++));
    }
}
```

inoutmex.h

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
template <typename T> 
void transferarray1(const mxArray *ix, vector<T>&V);
```

These 3 files are all under one directory. I think it must be related to link problem. 
I ran the command `mex test.cpp` in matlab command line. It gives the link error. Any suggestion will be appreciate.

Comment: You need to instantiate the template for the type you intend to use it with. See the linked Q&A for ways to do so. -- As a side-comment (not related to your problem): you should always include the header file in the source file that implements those functions. That is, `inoutmex.cpp` should include `inoutmex.h`. This allows the compiler to give error messages if the function signatures don't match.